# Once Scheduled Thread Pool is finished change the text of a JButton

Tags: java, swing

I have a program that opens RFID readers when a button on my GUI is pressed. This all works fine. I am using a ScheduledThreadPool to close the RFID readers after a certain time as shown below:

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).schedule(() -> {
        try {
            phid1.close();
            phid2.close();
        } catch (PhidgetException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        WalletLocatorInterface.infoTextArea.append("\nClosed RFIDs\n\n");
        WalletLocatorInterface.infoTextArea.append("Final Wallet Locations:\n");          
        try {
            getLocations();
        } catch (SQLException e1) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
        WalletLocatorInterface.trackingButton.setText("Start Tracking"); // this does not change the text on the button
    }, TimeOptionWindow.getTime(), TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

Once the Jbutton on the GUI interface is pressed the text on the button is changed to "Tracking...", however one the thread has ended i want to change the text back to "Start Tracking".

However i am having difficulties as the text on the button is not changing back. Does anyone know how i might fix this? or is it even possible? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

## Access widgets only in the user-interface thread

```
WalletLocatorInterface.trackingButton.setText("Start Tracking"); // this does not change the text on the button
```

***Never*** interact with Swing widgets from another thread.  Study the Oracle Tutorial on [Concurrency in Swing](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/). You may get away with it on occasion, or you may cause terrible things to happen to your app at runtime.

## Keep your executor

```
Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1).schedule(
```

Do not instantiate a thread pool and executor each time you have a task at hand. Keep the executor around. In most situations you would want to keep the same executor object around for the entire run of your app. Call the executor’s `schedule` method repeatedly, once each time you have a job to do. Consider using multiple threads in your pool rather than one, depending on your needs.

Each time you call `Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)` you are instantiating another executor with another thread pool (of a single thread). Do this three times and you have three executers each with a pool of a single-thread for a total of three threads. Instead, instantiate an executor backed by a single thread pool of three threads. Then submit a series of tasks to that executor. The submitted tasks will be run on any of the three threads, as that is the job of the executor: assign tasks to threads.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newScheduledThreadPool​​( 3 ) ; // Keep around a reference to this executor service.
… // Do some other stuff
scheduledExecutorService.schedule( () -> { System.out.println( "Eat early breakfast." ) } , … ) ;
… // Do some other stuff
int snacksCount = 3 ;
for( int i = 1 ; i <= snacksCount ; I ++ ) {
   scheduledExecutorService.schedule( () -> { System.out.println( "Eat snack." ) }  , … ) ;
}
… // Do some other stuff
scheduledExecutorService.schedule( () -> { System.out.println( "Eat lunch." ) }  , … ) ;
… // Do some other stuff
scheduledExecutorService.schedule( () -> { System.out.println( "Eat dinner." ) }  , … ) ;
… // Do some other stuff
scheduledExecutorService.shutdown() ;  // Always shut down your executor service. Otherwise, its pool of threads may continue indefinitely, even beyond the run of your app.
```

**Important:** Note that with multiple threads in play, the scheduled tasks may not execute in the order submitted. Dinner might be eaten before lunch, for example. If the order is important, use a single-thread pool.

If you do use a single-thread pool for this reason, make your code more self documenting by calling [`Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor()) rather than [`Executors.newScheduledThreadPool(1)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newScheduledThreadPool(int)) as seen in your Question. Use the variant taking a pool size argument suggests to the reading programmer that she can blithely change that argument later when editing the code. And of course too, explain in prose in a code-comment.

```
ScheduledExecutorService scheduledExecutorService = Executors.newSingleThreadScheduledExecutor() ; // *Must* use only a *single* thread pool, to ensure our meal-eating tasks execute in the order they were submitted.
```

FYI: **Concurrent programming is *very* tricky**. Eventually I suggest reading [*Java Concurrency in Practice*](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/127932.Java_Concurrency_in_Practice)
by Brian Goetz et al..

Comment: Ok thanks, all good information. Im not sure what you mean by "Keep the executor around." could you explain that for me?

Comment: @henry434 I added more prose and code example to show the use of a variable to hold a reference to an instantiated executor service. Then we call that executor service multiple times — the *same* executor service, not a new one for each task.